# Runtime error after compiling AIR application with ant script

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, ant, air, flex4

I'm getting a VerifyError: Error #1014: Class spark.components::WindowedApplication could not be found. error when running my AIR app from my Ant script. 
My app uses the extendedDesktop profile (for NativeProcess). I'm using Flash SDK 4.6 and I can compile, run and package the project in Flash Builder 4.6. I'd like to be able to do all of these things with an Ant script.

I'm having the same problem as this question:
[Compiling AIR application with Ant Task (WindowedApplication could not be found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241762/compiling-air-application-with-ant-task-windowedapplication-could-not-be-found)

My application compiles with the ant script but when I try to run it. I get this error followed by a bunch more not found errors.

> VerifyError: Error #1014: Class spark.components::WindowedApplication could not be found.
>
> at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
>     at mx.managers::SystemManager/deferredNextFrame()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:278]
>     at mx.managers::SystemManager/preloader_preloaderDocFrameReadyHandler()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2627]
>     at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
>     at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
>     at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:515]
>     at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
>     at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

some of the other errors:

> VerifyError: Error #1014: Class IFlexAsset could not be found.
>   VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.core::FontAsset could not be found.
>   VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.core::SpriteAsset could not be found.
>   VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.core::BitmapAsset could not be found.

Here is the compile target of my ant script

```
<target name="compile" depends="init">
  <mxmlc file="${MAIN_SOURCE_FILE}" 
        output="${DEBUG_DIR}/${APP_NAME}.swf"
        services="${APP_ROOT}/services/flex/services-config.xml" 
        configname="air"
        actionscript-file-encoding="UTF-8" fork="true">
    <locale>en_US</locale>
    <static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>true</static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>

    <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/air-config.xml"/>
    <source-path path-element="${APP_ROOT}/src"/>
    <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks"/>
    <source-path path-element="${APP_ROOT}/../MyLib/src"/>

    <compiler.external-library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks" append="true">
        <include name="libs/air" />
        </compiler.external-library-path>

    <compiler.library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks" append="true">
                    <include name="libs" />
            <include name="libs/mx" />
            <include name="libs/air" />
                    <include name="locale/{locale}" />
                </compiler.library-path>
    <compiler.library-path dir="${APP_ROOT}" append="true">
                    <include name="libs" />
                    <include name="libs/player" />
                </compiler.library-path> 
    <define name="CONFIG::debugging" value="false"/>

     <compiler.debug>true</compiler.debug>             
  </mxmlc>
  <copy filtering="true" file="${APP_DESCRIPTOR}" tofile="${APP_DEBUG_DESCRIPTOR}" />
        <replace file="${APP_DEBUG_DESCRIPTOR}">
            <replacefilter token="[This value will be overwritten by Flash Builder in the output app.xml]" value="${APP_NAME}.swf"/>
        </replace>
</target>
```

Here is the run target of my ant script

```
<target name="test" depends="compile">
    <exec executable="${ADL}">
        <arg value="${APP_DEBUG_DESCRIPTOR}"/>
    </exec> 
</target>
```

I've also tried using ADT to package the project as a .dmg and installing it. It installs but immediately exits when I run the installed version. 
Here is the package target from my ant script.

```
<target name="package" >
    <java jar="${ADT.JAR}" fork="true" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="-package"/>
        <arg value="-storetype"/>
        <arg value="${STORETYPE}"/>
        <arg value="-keystore"/>
        <arg value="${KEYSTORE}"/>
        <arg value="-storepass"/>
        <arg value="${KEYSTORE_PASS}"/>
        <!-- Target -->
        <arg value="-target"/>
        <arg value="native"/>
        <!-- Output -->
        <arg value="${PACKAGE_NAME}"/>
        <!-- App XML -->
        <arg value="${APP_DEBUG_DESCRIPTOR}"/>
        <!-- Include all files from the bin directory -->
        <arg value="-C"/>
        <arg value="${DEBUG_DIR}"/>
        <arg value="${APP_NAME}.swf"/>
        <arg value="-C"/>
        <arg value="src"/>
        <arg value="images"/>
        <arg value="-C"/>
        <arg value="src"/>
        <arg value="process"/>
        <arg value="-C"/>
        <arg value="src"/>
        <arg value="assets"/>
        <arg value="-C"/>
        <arg value="src"/>
        <arg value="styles"/>
    </java>
    <echo message="Finished packaging ${PACKAGE_NAME}"/>
</target>
```

Comment: If I just copy in the .swf created by the Flash builder build, it runs so I think the problem is related to the way it is being compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the external-library-path to only include the airglobal.swc and that got me past this error.

```
<compiler.external-library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/libs/air" append="true">
   <include name="airglobal.swc" />
</compiler.external-library-path>
```

I think including the entire air folder as an external library was causing the a bunch of .swc to be omitted from linking.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem in FlashDevelop, where app builded ok but in the runtime there was "error 1014: spark components Application not found".

Your answer about changing external library paths helped me pinpoint the problem. Basically, I removed paths from Project options -> tab Compiler Options, and left only:

```
Intrinsic Libraries: Library\AS3\frameworks\Flex4
```

And inside SWC libraries I left any other third party libraries I'm using. Also there is a FLVPlayback.swc (compiled inside Flash CS), for using FLVPlayback inside AS3 code. In this way I can use this Flex/Spark component inside normal AS3 application.